# Get pointer to function declared into namespace

Tags: c++, c++11, namespaces, function-pointers

I wanted to count the spaces from a `std::string`. Very simple task for `std::count_if` so I wrote this code:

```
std::cout<<std::count_if(str.cbegin(), str.cend(), &std::isspace);
```

and... compiler error (xcode): `No matching function for call to 'count_if'`

I changed to:

```
std::cout<<std::count_if(str.cbegin(), str.cend(), &isspace);
```

and the compiler error is not there anymore.

Can you please explain me what is the problem with the first line? Am I missing something when getting the function pointer when the function is in a namespace?Is this somehow ADL related as `isspace` and `count_if` are from the same namespace?

EDIT:

Complete build log:

> Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/c++/v1/algorithm:1097:1:
>   Candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument
>   '_Predicate'

Comment: I'll bet that the error message you show is not the only message in the build log. Please show the complete log.

Comment: You cannot safely do that because `std::isspace` can be overloaded. Also unsafe is blindly passing `char`s into it. You should use something (such as a lambda) that explicitly calls `std::isspace` with the `char` converted to an `unsigned char`.

Comment: @chris my first implementation used lambdas, but it seems like overkill as I just return the result from isspace. Now I'm interested why is there a difference when I don't fully qualify the function...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is related to the includes (either order and/or presence).

There are two `std::isspace` functions, one taking a single argument, the other taking 2 arguments. One first is declared in `<cctype>` and the second in `<locale>`.

```
int isspace ( int c );
```

And

```
template <class charT>
  bool isspace (charT c, const locale& loc);
```

Typically, with C++11, the count can can be written as

```
std::count_if(str.cbegin(), str.cend(), [](char c) {
  return std::isspace(c, std::locale());
});
```

Comment: @Felics Because there is only one `isspace`.

Comment: @Felics, The `cctype` one takes no template parameters, I think your error hints at that.

Comment: @Felics, Because `std::isspace` is only overloaded within `std`. However, within `<cctype>`, an implementation can **optionally** lift the C version to the global namespace. It can't do that with the `<locale>` one. To guarantee that `::isspace` exists, you need to include `<ctype.h>` or lift it yourself, but `<ctype.h>` is deprecated and lifting it yourself is poor coding style, and a problem if the one in `<locale>` is also lifted.

Comment: You'll want to change `char` to `unsigned char` to avoid possible overflow issues. You could also do `std::count_if(str.cbegin(), str.cend(), std::isspace<unsigned char>);`.

Comment: @0x499602D2 I need to use std::bind as std::isspace require locale also

Comment: @Felics Oh yeah that's right. Well you can just change `char c` to `unsigned char c` in the lambda.

Comment: @Felics For a more generic version, you can use `decltype(*str.cbegin())` instead of `char` as an argument to the lambda. It is a bit verbose, but if the character type in `str` where to change, the `decltype` would pick up the changes.